# Convert compiled dom to html code in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive which has a `postLink`, and I compiled some html code and render it by angularjs. But the problem is I can't get the html code from the generated DOM.

My code is:

```
app.directive("showResultAsText", ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
         compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            console.log('compile');
            var watchModal = tAttrs["showResultAsText"];
            var elem = jQuery(tElement);
            var oriHtml = elem.html();
            elem.empty();
            return {
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    scope.$watch(function () {
                        return scope.$eval(watchModal);
                    }, function (newVal) {
                        if (newVal) {
                            var s = $compile(angular.element(oriHtml))(scope);
                            console.log(s);
                            console.log(s[0]);
                            console.log(s[0].outerHTML);
                            console.log($('<div>').append(s[0]).html());
                            iElement.text(s[0].outerHTML);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see I used `console.log` to print the value of `s`. And in the console, it outputs:

[image]

You can see `console.log(s)` and `console.log(s[0])` have many information, but when I use `outerHTML`,  the inner buttons are all missing.

I also tried to use jquery: `jQuery(s[0]).html()`, but the same happened.

What is the correct way of convert that `s` to html code?

Comment: Can you explain why you need compiled html code? Actually keep in mind that `$compile` service do not only generate html, but also binds events to elements etc. So you can't re-use that html several times anyway.

Comment: I just want to show the generated html as text in the page, that I can copy it to somewhere else. Like a code generator

Comment: can you explain why you need a directive? if not absolutely necessary, it's not the angular-way to modify the DOM directly..

Answer (score 4):

It'd be easier if you could provide a plunkr / jsFiddle-example, but I think I know what's wrong. You're getting fooled by the console - when you you do console.log(s) it doesn't get logged immediately (it's async) - the console gets a reference to the dom element s[0], and by the time it's ready to print angular is done with it's rendering. On the other hand, s[0].outerHTML and s.html() are synchronous, so you get the pre-angular rendered result. To fix this you could just do a simple setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(s[0].outerHTML); });
```

Angular should now have time to do it's rendering before the callback (I don't think you need a delay, but I might be wrong). You can also use the angular $timeout-service which wraps the callback-function with $scope.$apply - see [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout)