# compiling a template into a string in angular without a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to add some html into a tinyMCE textarea (tinyMCE can show html inside those **editable** textareas while allowing the user to manipulate them live).

So, lets say my template is:

```
var template = '<span>hello {{ user.name }}</span>'
```

I'm trying to:

1. compile the template with the current **controller**'s scope.
2. stringify it into a varialbe (after it was compiled)
3. concat it to the end of the tinyMCE editor.

my controller's code is:

```
// [...]
var user = {};
user.name = "john";
$scope.user = user;

$templateRequest('<PATH_TO_TEMPLATE>').then(function() {
  var linkingFunc = $compile(template);

  // if I understand correctly, this should replace the user.name with "john"
  var parsedTemplate = linkingFunc($scope);
  console.log(parsedTemplate.prop('outerHTML'));
});
// [...]
```

The output of `parsedTemplate.prop('outerHTML')` is:

```
<span>hello {{ user.name }}</span>
```

Does it get rendered only if I inject it to the DOM after linking it to the scope?

is there a way to get it compiled in the javascript **without** rendering it back?

I'm trying to get some sort of `var templateWITHOUTVariables` which will euqal `<span>hello john</span>`

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565835/convert-compiled-dom-to-html-code-in-angularjs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008280/angularjs-using-compile-on-html-that-contains-directives-with-templateurl

Comment: @FrailWords I'm not sure how this helps me. it requires a digest which I can't do since I'm in a middle of a digest. If I try to access the template on the DOM without a digest, I see the unrendered template.
I can't digest even if I create a new scope that is unrelated to the current controller's scope.

Comment: @FrailWords Also, I was hoping to find a solution without injecting the template back to the DOM in order to render it (as mentioned in my question). The question you linked doesn't tackle that at all since the OP wanted the template injected back into the DOM tree

Comment: Running `$digest` doesn't mandate injection back into DOM.  Those posts are basically pointing in the direction that once you `$compile` your HTML string with the current scope, it may not immediately be available to the console.log statement unless you run a `$digest` cycle or put it inside a '$timeout` like so - `$timeout(function() {console.log(parsedTemplate.prop('outerHTML')) });`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @FrailWords, I solved this using `$timeout`.

So my code looks like this:

```
var user = {};
user.name = "john";
$scope.user = user;

$templateRequest('<PATH_TO_TEMPLATE>').then(function() {
  var parsedTemplate = $compile(template)($scope); // at this point, the template isn't processed yet
  //timeout in order to get the template processed
  $timeout(function() {
    console.log(parsedTemplate.prop('innerHTML');
  })
});
```

output:

```
<span>hello john</span>
```

When the `$timeout` executes, the `$digest` process already finished processing the `parsedTemplate`.